# unstack "multi-indexed" column| in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

in pandas I have a dataframe as follows (first line is the column, second is just a row now)

```
   2012    2013      2012    2013
   women   women     men     men
0  14       43        24       45
1  34       54        35       65
```

and would like to get it like

```
       women    men
2012 0  14       24 
2012 1  34       35 
2013 0  43       45 
2013 1  54       65
```

using df.stack, df.unstack did not get anywhere?

Any elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   2012      2013
  women men women men
0     0   1     2   3
1     4   5     6   7
```

the idea is to first stack the first level of the column to the first level of index, and then swap two indices ([pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html))

```
In [6]: df.stack(level=0).swaplevel(0,1,axis=0)
Out[6]: 
        men  women
2012 0    1      0
2013 0    3      2
2012 1    5      4
2013 1    7      6
```

Comment: This answer could be improved with some commentary explaining what you've done and why you've done it. (Someone recommended deletion - I disputed that, because this looks like a fine start to an answer to me.)

Answer (score 0):

`df.stack` is most likely what you want.  See below, you do need to specify that you want the first level.

```
In [79]: df = pd.DataFrame(0., index=[0,1], columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2012,2013], ['women','men']]))

In [83]: df.stack(level=0)
Out[83]: 
        men  women
0 2012    0      0
  2013    0      0
1 2012    0      0
  2013    0      0
```